# Manter sessão ativa pra múltiplas requisições usando CURL esta muito lenta

Tags: php, libcurl, batch, http-request

Fiz um script para postar anúncios automaticamente em um site de classificados para um determinado usuário.
Eu armazeno os ID anúncios localmente no banco de dados, depois com o CURL, eu faço login, e depois um loop em cada ID de anuncio para ativa-lo na data correspondente.

Porém isso está tomando demasiado tempo, chegando a dar timeout, pois uso um CURL para cada ID de anuncio.

Gostaria de saber se há uma forma de acelerar o processo. Pesquisando achei o Persistent/keepalive e o `curl_multi_init()`.

Mas não sei bem como usa-los.

Exemplo do meu codigo:

```
ob_start(); 
include_once("../includes/db_connect.php");
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE (data_publicacao = (now() + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) OR data_publicacao 0){

  while($annuncio = mysql_fetch_object($sql)){
    $annunci[] = trim($annuncio->url);
  }
  $url="http://sitedeanuncios.com/?page=my_profile";

  $cookie = dirname(__FILE__).'/cookies/cookies.txt';

  $username=""; 
  $password=""; 
  $postdata = "email=".$username."&password=".$password;

  $headers[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
  $headers[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";

  $ch = curl_init();
  ///////LOGIN UNICO 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://sitedeanuncios.com");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,  '');
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
  $result = curl_exec ($ch);  



  foreach ($annunci as $key => $id_anuncio) {

  //////////PAGAMENTO
  $url = 'http://sitedeanuncios.com/pay/metodopay=credit&idp='.$id_anuncio;
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://sitedeanuncios.com");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,  '');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); 
  curl_exec ($ch);
  // //////////PUBLICACAO
  $url = 'http://sitedeanuncios.com/publish&idp='.$id_anuncio;
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,  '');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); 
  curl_exec($ch); 
  curl_close($ch);

  ob_flush();

  }
}

ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: Isso é caso para rodar o script PHP via console/shell, aí não tem problema de timeout.

Comment: Completando o que o Bacco falou você pode fazer o loop da variável já criada. Ao invés de iniciar um novo init curl. Isso reduz o tempo de handshake do SSL, se usar.

Comment: Qual sessão quer manter, a da conexão ou do cookie de sessão?

Comment: Sessão do cookie, uso cookiejar para salvar e faço o loop com essa mesma sessão ativa, para evitar fazer login varias vezes.

Comment: @FabioWeydson mas se já esta usando o cookiejar, então a primeira parte funciona, só falta então resolver a perfomance? Será que nã é algo no teu código? Tem como postar um exemplo semelhante ao que fez?